Optimizing using Cython, what else could be done here? How to replace str with C's char
I'm trying to optimize a minimax implementation and profiling says the majority of the time is spent in the following three functions. This is my first time trying cython and I want to get the most out of it despite knowing little.
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef float get_absolute_value(str piece, bint is_white, int row, int col):
    cdef str type = piece.lower()
    
    if type == 'p':
        return 10 + (pawn_eval_white[row][col] if is_white else pawn_eval_black[row][col])
    elif type == 'n':
        return 30 + knight_eval[row][col]
    elif type == 'b':
        return 30 + (bishop_eval_white[row][col] if is_white else bishop_eval_black[row][col])
    elif type == 'r':
        return 50 + (rook_eval_white[row][col] if is_white else rook_eval_black[row][col])
    elif type == 'q':
        return 90 + queen_eval[row][col]
    elif type == 'k':
        return 900 + (king_eval_white[row][col] if is_white else king_eval_black[row][col])

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef float get_piece_value(str piece, bint is_white, int row, int col):
    if piece == ' ':
        return 0
    cdef float abs_val = get_absolute_value(piece, is_white, row, col)
    cdef float piece_value = abs_val if is_white else -abs_val
    return piece_value

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef float evaluate_board(list[list[str]] board):
    cdef int row, col
    cdef str piece
    cdef bint is_white
    cdef float total_value = 0.0
    for row in range(8):
        for col in range(8):
            piece = board[row][col]
            if piece == ' ':
                continue
            is_white = piece.isupper()
            total_value += get_piece_value(piece, is_white, row, col)
    return total_value

GPT suggested these annotations for now.
I suspect that the python calls to isupper() and lower() may be slowing things down given I'm calling these functions many times but GPT says these methods should be compiled into C with little hit to performance. Profiling supports this as cProfile won't give me the stats on these specific calls as they aren't in Python. Is there any obvious way to optimize these methods further than what I've added already?
I tried replacing the str declarations with char so that I can try to see if the method calls can be done using C code but it won't simply convert and this can't just be mapped as is. If I could I would use the following implementation instead as an example
cdef float get_absolute_value(char piece, bint is_white, int row, int col):
    cdef char type
    if ord(piece) >= 65 and ord(piece) <= 90:  # Uppercase letters
        type = chr(ord(piece) + 32)  # Convert to lowercase
    else:
        type = piece  # Already lowercase
    ...

and similarly for the other isupper call.
I haven't tried converting the lists in the first function to C arrays which was a GPT suggestion and am unsure if this would help that much. They are of type list[list[str]].

General advice: I advise you to rely more on profiling and be very careful about GPT-like tools which are not great when it comes to improve the performance of codes IMHO. Optimization if often dependent of a lot of factors and some of them are unknown to the model (and it is often not able to precisely understand the relations, especially for low-level stuff). Still it can sometimes help when you have no idea and profiling is not easy to do or does not give much information.

"GPT says these methods should be compiled into C with little hit to performance" This is the kind of case where the context matters a lot and it misses it. While the functions themselves are pretty efficient to compute the string, what is slow is the creation of a new CPython objects. You should really avoid creating new strings. The thing is CPython strings are immutable so the best is not to use strings at all. In fact you should avoid all kind of CPython objects. The rule of thumb is : native types are fast,  (dynamically allocated ref-counted GIL-locked) CPython objects are slow.

The suggestion about using C array is a good one. This avoid creating objects. However, there is a better alternative for sake of readability (a more pythonic one): using Numpy with Cython views. More specifically a 2D Numpy array of 1 char should be OK. Integer and enums are good too (if not better).

You're indexing into a structure using python int and I'm reasonably sure you shouldn't be doing that but there's not enough context

I'm not sure what you're hoping to achieve by using Cython in these examples. If you're lloking for runtime optimisation you should probably take a look at @jit from Numba

@SIGHUP Not sure why you say that. This is the sort of task that Cython should do quite well at (Numba would probably also be suitable)

This discussion is worth reading

@SIGHUP The difference in that question is that Numba has reimplemented some of Numpy but Cython hasn't, so if you're directly calling Numpy functions then it can be faster. They aren't doing that here so it's irrelevant. (The functions they're struggling with are on the builtin str class)

@DavidW If the issue is performance of the built-in functions then how would cython help to improve matters?

@SIGHUP because they're asking how they can write it using a C char instead of a Python string.

@SIGHUP Numba's JIT runs one for a particular instance of function. This is a method JIT based on the LLVM stack, not a tracing JIT like PyPy. Thus, there is no reason to believe Numba can be faster here unless the OP use Numpy (and even here Cython can be fast too if used correctly). In fact, Numba strings operations are slow (especially UTF-8 ones)

Thanks all, after fixing an unrelated bug these functions aren't being called as often with little need to optimize them further and focus is now in optimizing other parts.
